# Browserslist not honored in Angular 15

Tags: javascript, angular, browserslist

I want to compile an Angular 15 project which should run on Chrome 75 for Android.

Angular's documentation [claims that this is browser is not supported](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support). However the documentation also [claims that it has support for browserslist to specify compatability](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility).

Does that mean that the browserslist can only be used to further limit the supported browsers and not increase the support?
I don't find Angular's documentation very clear on this point.

Here's an example project where the problem can be seen:

First we create a new project and build it:

```
$ ng new foo --routing --style css
$ cd foo
$ npm ci
$ npm run build
```

The js output contains the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator, which is not supported in Chrome 75:

```
$ grep -oE '.{20}\\?\\..{20}' dist/foo/main.*.js
egate:r}=si;return r?.setTimeout?r.setTime
egate:t}=si;return(t?.clearTimeout||clearT
on td(e){return ne(e?.lift)}function Se(e)
on sd(e){return ne(e?.then)}function ad(e)
...
```

To ensure compatibility we try to use the browserslist support in Angular:

```
$ ng generate config browserslist
$ echo 'ChromeAndroid >= 75' >> .browserslistrc
$ cat .browserslistrc
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# For the full list of supported browsers by the Angular framework, please see:
# https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist

last 2 Chrome versions
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
ChromeAndroid >= 75
```

Building again, we see that the built javascript still uses the optional chaining operator:

```
$ npm run build
$ grep -oE '.{20}\\?\\..{20}' dist/foo/main.*.js
egate:r}=si;return r?.setTimeout?r.setTime
egate:t}=si;return(t?.clearTimeout||clearT
on td(e){return ne(e?.lift)}function Se(e)
on sd(e){return ne(e?.then)}function ad(e)
...
```

I would at least expect a warning or error from Angular that it will not respect my browserslist, if that is the case.

Comment: @Christian Yes. I have posted my solution as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Tyilo. I have also posted as answer how I fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by running `babel` manually on the `dist` folder after Angular is done building:

- I added `@babel/cli`, `@babel/core` and `@babel/preset-env` as dev dependencies.
- I created `babel.config.json` with the following contents:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "corejs": "3.29.1"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

- I added `"postbuild": "babel dist -d dist"` to my `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by adding the following line to the file polyfills.ts

```
import "core-js";
```